# Rails 5 - Managing Sessions Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a model `profile` and I have a devise model `user`. Currently, I have a custom method in my devise sessions controller to check for a profile_id through sessions as such:

```
  after_action :assign_profile, only: [:create]

  def assign_profile
    if session[:profile_id]
      @tutor.profile = Profile.find(session[:profile_id]) if @tutor.persisted?
      session.delete(:profile_id)
    end
  end
```

The problem here is it only recently came to my attention that I have to do some housekeeping on my sessions database. I recently ran `rake db:reset` in my development environment because I wanted to test a "fresh" site.

Now when logging in with a brand new `user`, I am encountering this error: `Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=4`. Clearly this means my sessions database has not been wiped. I have also tried clearing my browser's cache and restarting my rails server (I'm actually using incognito mode so that shouldn't be an issue) but that didn't work either.

I did some simple googling and the correct task to run, supposedly would be `rake db:sessions:clear`. However that gives me this error: `Don't know how to build task 'db:sessions:clear' (see --tasks)`.

So right now, I'm stuck. I can't test my website and I can't figure out how to clear out my development sessions database and start from scratch. (I'm running Rails 5.1)

Update:
I have tried including the following rake task (to run as a cron job in the future)

```
desc "Clear expired sessions"
task :clear_expired_sessions => :environment do
    sql = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE updated_at < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 days');"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "sessions" does not exist
```

Now I'm even more confused. Where is my sessions being stored then? Am i supposed to include [this active record session store gem](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) before being able to handle sessions in this fashion?

Update 2:
Restarting my computer has cleared the session data that has persisted. Though I would still greatly appreciate if someone could breakdown the problem that I was facing.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Rails secret key will invalidate all the cookies.

To clean all the temporary storage, which have effectively happened on your computer's restart, run the `rails tmp:clear` task - see the `tmp` [description here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#tmp).

Or you could create a custom task for clearing the cache store:

```
# lib/tasks/sessions.rake:
namespace :sessions do
  desc "Clear Rails.sessions"
  task :clear do
    ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(Rails.configuration.cache_‌​store).clear
    puts "Successfully cleared Rails.sessions!"
  end
end
```

And then run it with:

```
$ bundle exec rake sessions:clear
```

Comment: Any idea on clearing old sessions with rake tasks though? Since it seems my sessions are not storing to my db. I have no idea whats the command to run.

Comment: Updated my answer with a custom task for clearing the cache_store.